No matching step definition found for one or more steps
I'm working with specflow and visual studio. The thing is that it continues throwing the same message
"No matching step definition found for one or more steps." If I select the option to go to definition, it goes to the definition and also I can go to the steps defintion. The binding is correctly setted up and also the scope. Also the references of the project. The only way that I have to run my test is to clean the solution, build it and then at the first try it works, If I try to run it again, it display the same message "No matching step definition found for one or more steps"
I  have reinstalled specflow and visual studio but still, the issue persist.
Don't know what to do, any help?
I had tried reinstalling deleting the bin, and obj folders from my project, clean the solution and build it again, re install specflow and visual studio I expect that it can run multiple times my test without running over and over to clean the solution and then build it

You've tried basically everything I was going to recommend, except a couple things:

Delete the .vs folder at the root of your Visual Studio solution.

Clean the solution using Git (if you are using Git version control).
WARNING: this deletes all untracked files!

Close all Visual Studio windows.
Run git clean -fdx from the command line, which blows away all files that are not tracked by git (including the aforementioned .vs folder).
Open the solution in Visual Studio, clean and rebuild.



If that doesn't work, make sure you are on the latest version of the SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio, and SpecFlow NuGet package. The SpecFlow docs should have more information.
